# Fasting on the wedding day - when getting married right before or after a fast

Tags: halacha, minhag, fast-days, wedding

When a person gets married a day before Yom Kippur or a day after Tzon Gedalya - does he/she have to fast two days in a row?

Comment: Since one cannot fast the day before Yom Kippur, I assume you mean fast part of the day (prior to an early wedding). Still, I wonder if one is allowed to intend to fast on erev Yom Kippur for any duration?

Answer (score 7):

I got married on the day after tisha b'av :) and was told not to fast. However, the rav I asked said that there are 2 reasons to fast on the day of your wedding:

1. To make sure you're clear-headed at the wedding (i.e. don't drink)
2. As a kapparah (atonement)

So for 1. he advised me not to drink, and for 2 he said that I should accept upon myself to fast a short day in the following winter as a kapparah.

But, as msh210 said, you should ask your own LOR :)

Answer (score 6):

[*Nit'e Gavriel*, *Nisuin*](http://hebrewbooks.org/46545) 6:7 says that he doesn't fast the day after *Yom Kipur*, as his sins are already forgiven. (In 5:1, forgiveness of sins is one of the reasons given for his fasting.) See there for more details. 6:8 says that if it's hard for him to fast a day or two after a general fast day then he can break the fast. (5:3 says the same for every day, but only if it's "very" hard.) He does not discuss someone who marries before a fast, as far as I see. As always, for practical guidance, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).

Answer (score 6):

A friend of mine got married the day after Yom Kippur. At the end of Yom Kippur services, somebody showed him in the Chabad machzor the instructions that one shouldn't fast the day after Yom Kippur, with the exception of a Chatan who is getting married that day.

Answer (score 3):

**Before Taanis Esther:**

We got married on a Wednesday evening, the day before Taanis Esther which (in תשמ״ז) was a מוקדם being that Purim was on Sunday.

I asked Rav Neuwirth שליט״א (the author of שמירת שבת כהלכתה) if we needed to fast.

He showed me a  (שער הציון (ט״ז  in Hilchos Purim - תרפ״ו - that said that we did not have to fast in this case.

**After Yom Kippour:**

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 146:2 says that between Yom Kipour and Sukkoth the bride and groom do fast.